# I can't seem to add commands to Cortana

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp, cortana

I've recently installed Windows 10 and being a programmer I was thinking maybe I can personalize Cortana a bit.
I've done what mdsn told me and I've tried to create an test project as simple as possible from which I can iterate.
I've looked over a lot of topics but I could not find my problem.
What I find weird is that I can find my commands inside Cortana but Cortana doesn't seem to trigger them inside my app. It just brings the Bing Search. :(

Here is the proof that my command was registered.
[image: Cortana Command Added]

Here is the code:

```
protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ---------------------------

    try
    {
        // Install the main VCD. 
        StorageFile vcdStorageFile =
         await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(
           @"TestCommands.xml");

        await Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands.VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.
         InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync(vcdStorageFile);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Installing Voice Commands Failed: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}

protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle when app is launched by Cortana
    if (e.Kind == ActivationKind.VoiceCommand)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("It worked!!!");
    }
    base.OnActivated(e);
}
```

And the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
    <CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" Name="EatEverydayCommandSet_en-us">
        <Example>Eat everyday</Example>

        <Command Name="Eat_Every_Day">
            <Example>Eat everyday</Example>
            <ListenFor>Eat everyday</ListenFor>
            <Feedback>Eating</Feedback>
            <Navigate />
        </Command>
    </CommandSet>
</VoiceCommands>
```

Also I looked and I have my region configured to United States and Language to English.

Comment: Might seem odd to say but have you tried speaking to the Cortana app, by selecting the Cortana Microphone Button or saying "Hey, Cortana" before saying "Eat Everyday" - also could try changing it to listen for "Eat every day" as it could be listening for a different pronunciation for that word that you're saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted is right and with your code I can launch the app from Cortana. One possible reason that Cortana can't launch your app may be that you didn't set **CommandPrefix** or **AppName** element in your VCD file.

Although these two are optional child element of the CommandSet element. But they specify a user-friendly name for an app that a user can speak when giving a voice command. This is useful for apps with names that are long or are difficult to pronounce. If we don't set **CommandPrefix** or **AppName** element, uses need to use the app name with the voice command to execute in Cortana. For your case, according to the image you've posted, the complete command should be **"EatEveryday, Eat everyday"**.

`EatEveryday` is not a word in English. It's hard for Cortana to recognize it. In most case, you command will be recognized as "eat everyday eat everyday". As there is no app registered in Cortana whose name is "eat" or "eat everyday", Cortana will bring Bing Search to search it.

To test the voice command you've registered, you can try to type "EatEveryday Eat everyday" in Cortana like following:
[image]

This should be able to launch your app. And for better user experiences, I'd suggest you set the **CommandPrefix** or **AppName** element in your VCD file. For example, using following VCD file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
  <CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" Name="EatEverydayCommandSet_en-us">
    <CommandPrefix>Eat Application</CommandPrefix>
    <Example>Eat everyday</Example>

    <Command Name="Eat_Every_Day">
      <Example>Eat everyday</Example>
      <ListenFor>Eat everyday</ListenFor>
      <Feedback>Eating</Feedback>
      <Navigate />
    </Command>
  </CommandSet>
</VoiceCommands>
```

And then using the command "eat application eat everyday" to launch the app.

Comment: YES YES YES. Thanks a lot. I didn't realize I had to have a prefix. Do you have any idea if there is a way to do it without a CommandPrefix to say only "Eat everyday".

Comment: @DoNNNy I'm afraid you can only say "Eat everyday". If you do not use CommandPrefix then you can use AppName like in the official [Cortana voice command sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand). Or if you do not use all of them, you have to use your app name instead, like using "EatEveryday, Eat everyday".